# MySql. Сравнить две таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос для сравнения двух таблиц?
Есть две таблицы свойств вещества старая и новая:
`id_свойства, param1, param2. param1 + param2 = уникальны`

Есть еще две таблицы связь вещества и свойств вещества старая и новая:
`id_вещества, id_свойства id_вещества + id_свойства = уникальны`
Новая таблица в обоих случаях заполняется при полном обновлении свойств вещества. При каждом таком обновлении id_свойства меняется. У каждого вещества разное количество свойств и при обновлении свойства и их количество могут изменяться. Как можно (если возможно) составить запрос к БД чтобы вычислить список веществ у которых изменились свойства? Спасибо.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: `select * from new_table where not exist (select * from old_table)`

Comment: Ну или не `select *`, а `select id_вещества, id_свойства`

Comment: @MaxDown Запрос даст не только вещества, у которых изменились свойства, но и свежезанесённые (автор про них, правда, ничего не говорит..). Однако запрос не даст удалённые.

Comment: А что если в свойствах поменялось только id_свойства, и, соответственно, изменилась таблица привязки вещества к свойству? По сути осталось все так же, только id_свойства изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую попробовать запрос на подобие такого:

```
SELECT
  old_table.id_вещества
FROM
  old_table
JOIN
  new_table
ON
  old_table.param1 + old_table.param2 = new_table.param1 + new_table.param2
WHERE
  old_table.id_свойства <> new_table.id_свойства
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Так я получу новые id старых свойств:
    `SELECT
  t1.id
FROM
  properties_old t1
JOIN
  properties_new t2
ON
  CONCAT(t1.param1, t1.param2) = CONCAT(t2.param1, t2.param2)
WHERE
  t1.id <> t2.id`

Comment: Не понимаю как получить все substance_id (вещество) у которых изменились param1+param2. ID могло измениться, например, из-за удаления какого-то свойства (получаю списком по АПИ). ID поменялось при добавлении в БД сайта, но param1+param2 остались те же, что были связаны через таблицу substance_properties_old.

    `Таблица substance_properties_old`
    `substance_id(int), properties_id(int)`

    `Таблица substance_properties_new`
    `substance_id(int), properties_id(int)`